# Missing date on Amcharts x-axis

Tags: amcharts

I'm trying to build a simple graph. X-axis is month, Y-axis is value. Here is the demo of my graph

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
        "type": "xy",
        "theme": "light",
        "dataDateFormat": "DD-MM-YYYY",
        "graphs": [
            {
                "id":"g8",
                "balloon":{
                    "drop":true,
                    "adjustBorderColor":false,
                    "color":"#ffffff"
                },
                "bullet":"round",
                "bulletBorderAlpha":1,
                "bulletColor":"#FFFFFF",
                "bulletSize":5,
                "dashLength":0,
                "hideBulletsCount":50,
                "lineThickness":2,
                "lineColor":"#67b7dc",
                "title":"Store 8",
                "useLineColorForBulletBorder":true,
                "xField":"d1",
                "yField":"p1",
                "xAxis":"g8",
                "balloonText":"<span style='font-size:18px;'>$[[d2]]</span><br>07/1/2017-12/31/2017"
            }
        ],
        "valueAxes": [
            {
                "id": "g8",
                "axisAlpha": 1,
                "gridAlpha": 1,
                "axisColor": "#b0de09",
                "color": "#b0de09",
                "dashLength": 5,
                "centerLabelOnFullp": true,
                "position": "bottom",
                "type": "date",
                "minp": "DD-MM-YYYY",
                "markPeriodChange": false,
            }
        ],
        "dataProvider": [
            {
                "d1":"01/01/2017",
                "p1":"5353.9000"
            },{
                "d1":"02/01/2017",
                "p1":"5353.9000"
            },{
                "d1":"01/02/2017",
                "p1":"5288.9500"
            },{
                "d1":"01/03/2017",
                "p1":"6850.9900"
            },{
                "d1":"01/04/2017",
                "p1":"5543.1900"
            },{
                "d1":"01/05/2017",
                "p1":"5519.0100"
            },{
                "d1":"01/06/2017",
                "p1":"6191.7500"
            }
        ]
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/noroots/xru967ha/

I don't know why, but X-axis labels missing June and all labels looks like having left offset. How can I move it to the left and show missing month?

Comment: A serial chart seems more appropriate for your case. Why are you using XY instead?

Comment: Because this is just a sample. In original, it's contain more graph and 2 X-Axis. I couldn't realize it in serial graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add data items before and after without drawing points:

```
"dataProvider": [{
    "d1":"01/12/2016"
}, {
    "d1":"01/01/2017",
    "p1":"5353.9000"
}, ...
```

Please check the example here: https://jsfiddle.net/xru967ha/5/

**Old Answer**

Please check the example below. It's using [AmSerialChart](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart) and then the [datePadding](https://github.com/amcharts/tools/tree/master/datePadding) plugin to set 15 extra days at the beginning and the end of your data.

```
"categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true,
    "minPeriod": "MM",
    "prependPeriods": 0.5, // add 15 days start
    "appendPeriods": 0.5   // add 15 days to end
}
```

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",
    "marginRight": 40,
    "marginLeft": 60,
    "dataDateFormat": "DD-MM-YYYY",
    "valueAxes": [{
        "id": "v1",
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "position": "left",
        "ignoreAxisWidth": true,
        "dashLength": 5
    }],
    "graphs": [{
        "id": "g1",
        "balloon":{
          "drop":true,
          "adjustBorderColor":false,
          "color":"#ffffff"
        },
        "bullet": "round",
        "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
        "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
        "bulletSize": 5,
        "hideBulletsCount": 50,
        "lineThickness": 2,
        "lineColor":"#67b7dc",
        "title": "red line",
        "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
        "valueField": "p1",
        "balloonText": "<span style='font-size:18px;'>[[value]]</span>"
    }],
    "chartCursor": {
        "pan": true,
        "valueLineEnabled": true,
        "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
        "cursorAlpha":1,
        "cursorColor":"#258cbb",
        "limitToGraph":"g1",
        "valueLineAlpha":0.2,
        "valueZoomable":true
    },
    "categoryField": "d1",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "parseDates": true,
        "minorGridEnabled": true,
        "axisColor": "#b0de09",
        "color": "#b0de09",
        "dashLength": 5,
        "boldPeriodBeginning": false,
        "markPeriodChange": false,
        "minPeriod": "MM",
        "prependPeriods": 0.5,
        "appendPeriods": 0.5
    },
    "export": {
        "enabled": true
    },
    "dataProvider": [
  {
   "d1":"01/01/2017",
   "p1":"5353.9000"
  },{
   "d1":"02/01/2017",
   "p1":"5353.9000"
  },{
   "d1":"01/02/2017",
   "p1":"5288.9500"
  },{
   "d1":"01/03/2017",
   "p1":"6850.9900"
  },{
   "d1":"01/04/2017",
   "p1":"5543.1900"
  },{
   "d1":"01/05/2017",
   "p1":"5519.0100"
  },{
   "d1":"01/06/2017",
   "p1":"6191.7500"
  }
 ]
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
 width : 800px;
 height : 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/tools/datePadding/datePadding.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks great, but in my case I need something like this https://jsfiddle.net/noroots/xru967ha/2/ and I can't do this with serial.

Comment: Great! Thank you!